# Difficulty with propositional logic in prolog

Tags: prolog, propositional-calculus

I need to convert the following propositions into prolog code and I have do not understand how the operators work. I usually use java.

"Jeans are only casual, dress pants are only formal, kakis are only semi-formal, belts are not casual, black socks are acceptable anytime.
Casual = C, Semi-Formal = SF, Formal = F, Jeans = J, Dress pants = DP, Kakis = K, Belts = B, Black socks = BS.
J -> C, DP -> F, K -> SF, B -> !C, BS -> (C v SF v F)"

Here is the code I already have:

```
casual(jeans).
formal(dress_pants, belt, black_socks).
semiFormal(khakis).
formal(belt).
semiFormal(belt).
casual(black_socks).
formal(black_socks).
semiFormal(black_socks).
```

Comment: What are the inputs and outputs here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Informally, a unary predicate `p` can be viewed as a set **P** and, consequently, a literal `p(X)` can be viewed as the set membership test **X∈P**. Therefore, a goal `p(X)` will be **true** or **false** (i.e., a proposition), depending on whether **X** belongs to the set **P** or not.

The sentences "*Jeans are only casual, dress pants are only formal, kakis are only semi-formal, belts are not casual, black socks are acceptable anytime.*" can be represented as the sets:

- **casual** = {**jeans**, **black_socks**}.
- **formal** = {**dress_pants**, **belt**, **black_socks**}
- **semi_formal** = {**khakis**, **belt**, **black_socks**}

And these sets can be represented in Prolog by the facts:

```
casual(jeans).
casual(black_socks).

formal(dress_pants).
formal(belt).
formal(black_socks).

semi_formal(khakis).
semi_formal(belt).
semi_formal(black_socks).
```

Here are some Prolog queries about these facts:

```
?- casual(jeans).
true.

?- casual(belt).
false.

?- casual(X).
X = jeans ;
X = black_socks.

?- formal(X).
X = dress_pants ;
X = belt ;
X = black_socks.

?- semi_formal(X).
X = khakis ;
X = belt ;
X = black_socks.
```

Comment: Thank you so much! what if I wanted to create a function that can take in an dress code or a outfit and return the other. this is what I have so far: to_wear(Dcode, Ofit) :-
    clothes(Dcode, Ofit).